# How to share Entity classes across multiple Persistence Unit?

Tags: jpa, entity, persistence

How to share Entity classes across multiple Persistence Unit?

I have 2 MySql databases (dbOne, dbTWO) with the same table "users"

I would like to have an Entity class like this :

```
@Entity
public class User {
  ...
  ...
}
```

shared between the 2 PU (of dbONE and dbTWO).. (eclipse.persistence)

i tried with :

```
<persistence-unit name="one_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.model.User</class>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbONE"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  
  <persistence-unit name="two_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.model.User</class>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbTWO"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

without success..

Is it possible?..how can i do that?

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Comment: yes! i get an error during compilation with maven : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyProject: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.model.User_ -> [Help 1]

Comment: i tried also with maven-compiler-plugin v.3.5.1

Comment: Do you need the JPA Metamodel in with the Criteria API?

Comment: no! no need....

Comment: Do you build with Maven?

Comment: yes! maven-compiler-plugin 3.5.1

Comment: Is there a JPA model gen dependency?

Comment: no, no JPA model gen